# Невозможно открыть сгенерированный QR-код SVG в Adobe Illustrator

Tags: php, html, svg, qrcode, adobe-illustrator

Я генерирую QR-код, используя php-пакет composer [endroid/qr-code](https://github.com/endroid/qr-code).

Это так здорово, вот мои настройки PHP для генерации SVG.

// create QR code

```
$qrCode = QrCode::create($url)
            ->setEncoding(new Encoding('UTF-8'))
            ->setErrorCorrectionLevel(new ErrorCorrectionLevelLow())
            ->setSize(210)
            ->setMargin(0)
            ->setRoundBlockSizeMode(new RoundBlockSizeModeMargin())
            ->setForegroundColor(new Color(0,0,0))
            ->setBackgroundColor(new Color(255,255,255));
```

Который выводит этот потрясающий QR-код в формате SVG... (немного уменьшен для демонстрации)

Запустите фрагмент ниже, чтобы увидеть код SVG, работающий в HTML...

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="210px" height="210px" viewBox="0 0 210 210">
  <defs>
    <rect id="block" width="30" height="30" fill="#000000" />
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="210" height="210" fill="#ffffff" />
  <use x="0" y="0" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="30" y="0" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="60" y="0" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="90" y="0" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="120" y="0" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="150" y="0" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="180" y="0" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="0" y="30" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="180" y="30" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="0" y="60" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="60" y="60" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="90" y="60" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="120" y="60" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="180" y="60" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="0" y="90" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="60" y="90" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="90" y="90" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="120" y="90" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="180" y="90" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="0" y="120" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="60" y="120" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="90" y="120" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="120" y="120" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="180" y="120" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="0" y="150" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="180" y="150" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="0" y="180" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="30" y="180" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="60" y="180" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="90" y="180" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="120" y="180" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="150" y="180" href="#block"></use>
  <use x="180" y="180" href="#block"></use>
</svg>
```

**Но нет ничего, что я не перепробывал, чтобы мои QR-коды открывались в иллюстраторе.**

Этот код работает в моем предварительном просмотре `IDE`, предварительном просмотре `Mac`, он отлично открывается в `Chrome` и отлично отображается при использовании на html-страницах, но не открывается в **`Illustrator`**.
Когда я открываю в Illustrator, он показывает просто белое поле.

Почему этот код SVG не будет работать в Adobe Illustrator?
Как исправить код SVG для работы в Illustrator?

Я использую последнюю версию Adobe Illustrator 28.0.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Cannot open generated QR code SVG in Adobe Illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77572232/7394871) от участника  [@joshmoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888894/joshmoto).</sub>

Comment: Проверил на себе в Илл и не только. Похоже, что этот способ минификации SVG изображений за счёт `<defs>` и сопутствующим `<use>` никто не любит. Что, к слову, гуглится в один тык. Вам бы посмотреть настройки этой либы и поискать возможность экспортировать полноценную svg-шку без ссылок внутри. Думаю такая найдётся. Ну или намекните авторам.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/77572232/7394871

Comment: в чем смысл использования `use` если можно было просто копировать `rect` - даже меньше кода было бы

Comment: @Grundy так use в данном коде и есть копирование прямоугольника 30x30 с id="block"

Comment: Ну вопрос как раз в том и стоял - зачем use если можно было просто rect копировать, и defs не нужны сразу

Comment: @Grundy А как rect копировать без use? Для каждого rect полностью повторять все его атрибуты: x="";  y="";  width=""; height="" ;fill="" ? В случае использования `defs` атрибуты `rect` определяются один раз и с помощью `use `по id `block` копируются много раз. `<use x="60" y="90" href="#block"></use>"` Координаты x="60" y="90" располагают копию начального rect на новом месте. Вот если использовать простое копирование rect с повторением всех атрибутов, то кода точно будет больше.

Comment: ну если ты replace в тексте use на rect сделаешь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, Adobe Illustrator [еще не поддерживает](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-desktop-bugs/suggestions/45878884-problem-with-use-element-of-svg-files) атрибуты `href` и вместо него требуется `xlink:href`.

При внесении этого изменения вам также потребуется добавить атрибут `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` к корневому элементу.

На самом деле я думаю, что код, который вы используете для создания выходных данных, содержит команду `Force_xlink_href`, поэтому вам следует просто использовать ее, и все будет сделано за вас.

```
$builder->writerOptions([
    SvgWriter::WRITER_OPTION_FORCE_XLINK_HREF => true
]);
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77572495/7394871) от участника  [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson).</sub>